# using pythonanywhere to host a quart web app

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, quart

I'm trying to host my quart (aync flask) webapp on python anywhere. But whenever I run the site, I get this error:

```
2021-08-22 14:42:05,914: Error running WSGI application
2021-08-22 14:42:05,915: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quart'
2021-08-22 14:42:05,915:   File "/var/www/8au_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-08-22 14:42:05,915:     from app import app as application  # noqa
2021-08-22 14:42:05,915: 
2021-08-22 14:42:05,915:   File "/home/8au/site/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2021-08-22 14:42:05,915:     from quart import Quart, render_template, request, session, redirect, jsonify, abort
```

I have pip3 installed quart, and I am running on python3.9 I have no idea why this is happening. I have spent hours trying to fix it, and I'm unsure what to do next...

Comment: Quart is not supported in the standard libraries in Python Anywhere. You can use another cloud provider, or a different framework.

Comment: oh no! Thank you for letting me know about this... I guess ill try to convert my app to use flask instead :(

Comment: There is no async (ASGI) web apps support on PythonAnywhere yet. Flask would be fine.

Comment: Thanks guys. Really helpful. I switched to flask and got it up and running in minutes!